# JVectorMap map not clickable

Tags: javascript, arrays, maps, jvectormap

I use JVectorMap use SVG `world_mill` and the Map function, now my problem is that every setting I enter doesn't work like the color to the Marker, instead of using MultiMap it works.

My code

```
     new jvm.Map({  
        container: $("#div_map"),
        maxLevel: 1,
        main: {
            map: 'world_mill',
            backgroundColor:  "#fff",
            zoomOnScroll: true,
            zoomMax: 10,
            regionsSelectable: false,
            markersSelectable: false,
            hoverOpacity: 0.7,
            hoverColor: true,
            regionStyle: { initial: { fill: '#e7e7e7', "fill-opacity": 1, stroke: '#fff', "stroke-width": 0.01, "stroke-opacity": 1}, hover: { "fill-opacity": 0.5, cursor: 'default'}, selected: { fill:'rgba(72, 155, 224, 1)' }, selectedHover: { }},
            markerStyle: {initial: {fill:'rgba(72, 155, 224, 1)',stroke:'rgba(72, 155, 224, 0.2)',"stroke-width":4,r:2}, hover: {fill:'rgba(72, 155, 224, 1)', stroke:'rgba(72, 155, 224, 0.2)', "stroke-width":4, r:2}},
            markers: marker_data.map(function(h) {return {name: h.name, latLng: h.latLng}}),
            series: {regions: [{values: country_data, scale: ['#f1f1f1', '#fafafb'], normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'}]},
            zoomButtons : false,
        }
    });
```

The `marker_data` array is like this:

```
marker_data = [{"name" => "New York", "latLng" => [40.730610, -73.935242]}]
```

As I said if I use MultiMap instead it works, what I need is that the map is not clickable and only with the Map function is possible.

Can you help me?

Comment: Formatting the code and content

Comment: The `main` parameter shall be used **only** together with *multimaps*, see the other examples here: http://jvectormap.com/examples/markers-world/